# Можно ли поставить Adobe Photoshop на Windows Server 2003 и если да, то какую версию?

Tags: windows-server

Пытался ставить CS3. Пишет, что системные требования должны быть следующие:
Windows XP SP2-3
Windows Vista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам достаточно перейти в каталог Photoshop CS3/payloads/AdobePhotoshop10en_US_volume/ и изменить значение **"Server2003":{"Exclude":true}** на **"Server2003": {"Require":true}** в конце файла *AdobePhotoshop10en_US_volume.proxy.xml*